# Algorithm to Generate WaveLength Color Gradient in C#

Tags: c#, color-scheme

I am trying to generate the below Color Gradient ( the Color is blue at one end, and red at the other).

[image]
<sub>(source: [brothersoft.com](http://img.brothersoft.com/screenshots/softimage/w/wavelength-160945-1.jpeg))</sub>

I follow the suggestion [put forth here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011832/generate-color-gradient-in-c/2011839#2011839). This is my code:

```
int rMax = Color.Red.R;
int rMin = Color.Blue.R;
// ... and for B, G
var colorList = new List<Color>();
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    var rAverage = rMin + (int)((rMax - rMin) * i / size);
    // ... and for B, G
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(rAverage, gAverage, bAverage));
}
```

Although the result I *did* show a gradual, smooth transition from Red to Blue, but other intermediate color such as yellow and green didn't show up at all.

Anything I did wrong?

Comment: see [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should work with colors in the HSL color space, not RGB.  That allows you to smoothly change the hue value from 0 (red) to 1 (violet).  The System.Drawing.Color structure allows converting from RBG to HSL (GetHue etc) but not the other way.  The math is [simple though](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Conversion_from_HSL_to_RGB).

Comment: ...That is exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

```
int rMax = Color.Red.R; 
int rMin = Color.Blue.R; 
// ... and for B, G 
var colorList = new List<Color>(); 
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) 
{ 
    var rAverage = rMin + (int)((rMax - rMin) * i / size); 
    // ... and for B, G 
    colorList.Add(Color.FromArgb(rAverage, gAverage, bAverage)); 
}
```

You are setting `rMin = 0` and `rMax = 255`.  Thus you are essentially setting

```
rAverage = 255 * i / size;
```

You don't have the code for `gAverage` and `bAverage` listed, but if it were truly equivalent you'd be seeing a gradual trasition from black->gray->white, with no other hues at all.

It seems likely that what you want is to iterate over the different hues at a constant lightness/saturation.  See [here](http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm) for an example C# class which does that, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Conversion_from_HSL_to_RGB) for an explanation of the equation.