# Sorting a list of RGB triplets into a spectrum

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, color-space, spectrum, hsv

I have a list of RGB triplets, and I'd like to plot them in such a way that they form something like a spectrum.

I've converted them to HSV, which people seem to recommend.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import colorsys

def make_rainbow_rgb(colors, width, height):
    """colors is an array of RGB tuples, with values between 0 and 255"""

    img = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height))
    canvas = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    def hsl(x):
        to_float = lambda x : x / 255.0
        (r, g, b) = map(to_float, x)
        h, s, l = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r,g,b)
        h = h if 0 < h else 1 # 0 -> 1
        return h, s, l

    rainbow = sorted(colors, key=hsl)

    dx = width / float(len(colors)) 
    x = 0
    y = height / 2.0
    for rgb in rainbow:
        canvas.line((x, y, x + dx, y), width=height, fill=rgb)
        x += dx
    img.show()
```

However, the result doesn't look very much like a nice rainbow-y spectrum. I suspect I need to either convert to a different color space or handle the HSL triplet differently.

[image: this doesn't look like a spectrum]

Does anyone know what I need to do to make this data look roughly like a rainbow?

**Update:**

I was playing around with Hilbert curves and revisited this problem. Sorting the RGB values (same colors in both images) by their position along a Hilbert curve yields an interesting (if still not entirely satisfying) result:

[image: RGB values sorted along a Hilbert curve.]

Comment: Please read this, then reconsider that you're doing: http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Equations.html.  Spectrum is a single wavelength value, not HSL triple or anything like it.  The equation isn't simple and all RGB colors do NOT have a place on the spectrum.  Also, this may be helpful: http://www.pfk.ff.vu.lt/cie/1931CIE_explanation.htm.  You really need to rethink what you're doing.

Comment: @S.Lott -- yeah, I'm aware that technically this is a fool's errand. I don't really need anything related to physical light, just something that exhibits a maximally pleasing gradient (i.e. minimizes perceptual discontinuity).

Comment: Update -- I've decided to plot the colors on two axes, hue and saturation, allowing brightness to vary naturally. The results look good (but take up more room)

Comment: if you are looking for [real spectral colors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) look especially the R,G,B  graphs and try to sort the colors in similar manner. and then reorder "same" colors by intensities so you do not have too much bumps...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to convert a three-dimensional space into a one-dimensional space. There's no guarantee that you can make a pleasing rainbow out of it, as Oli says.

What you can do is "bucket" the colors into a few different categories based on saturation and value/lightness, and then sort within the categories, to get several independent gradients. For example, high-saturation colors first for the classic rainbow, then mid-saturation high-value colors (pastels), then low-saturation (grays).

Alternately, if all you care about is the rainbow, convert to hsl, then slam saturation to 1.0 and value to 0.5, convert back to rgb and render that instead of the original color.

Comment: I like the idea of separate rainbows. I'll play with that. Thanks

Comment: As rephorm say in is answer, you can use Hibert curve to reduce 3D to 2D space.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably you are sorting by hue (i.e. *H*)?  That will give a nice result if *S* and *L* (or *V*) are constant, but if they are varying independently, then you will get a bit of a mess!

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorting by h, then s, then l, and the variability of those last 2 leads to a mess. I'm wondering if there's some function of h, s, and l that will make something pretty.

Comment: @Jason: In general, no.  As @Russell says in his answer, you're trying to fold a 3D space into a 1D line.  You won't be able to avoid discontinuities, unless you actually modify your input colours.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some rainbows I made recently, you can modify the idea to do what you want

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw  # pip install pillow
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

strip_h, strip_w = 100, 720
strip = 255*np.ones((strip_h,strip_w,3), dtype='uint8')
image_val = Image.fromarray(strip)
image_sat = Image.fromarray(strip)
draw0 = ImageDraw.Draw(image_val)
draw1 = ImageDraw.Draw(image_sat)
for y in range(strip_h):
    for x in range(strip_w):
        draw0.point([x, y], fill='hsl(%d,%d%%,%d%%)'%(x%360,y,50))
        draw1.point([x, y], fill='hsl(%d,%d%%,%d%%)'%(x%360,100,y))

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.imshow(image_val)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.imshow(image_sat)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this code fills space with a nice range of colors. My problem is that I have a list of colors that I want to rainbow-ify. Kind of the opposite problem. Thanks for the code, though.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting method for reducing dimensionality of color spaces uses the space-filling [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve). Two relevant articles are:

- [Color Space Dimension Reduction](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/Color/CSDR) - overview of several methods for reducing dimensionality of color data
- [Portrait of the Hilbert Curve](http://corte.si/posts/code/hilbert/portrait/index.html) - detailed article about Hilbert curves and application to color-space dimensionality reduction

They both consider 3d -> 2d reduction, but the intermediate step of mapping to the 1d curve could be a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for 2 very interesting links!

Comment: Annoter exemple using Hilbert curve to sort image's pixels: http://www.poeschko.com/2011/09/extreme-geeky-tidying-up/

Answer (score 1):

This seems incorrect.

```
canvas.line((x, y, x + dx, y), width=height, fill=rgb)
```

Try this.

```
canvas.rectangle([(x, y), (x+dx, y+height)], fill=rgb)
```

Comment: They both produce the same thing, although I'll grant you that it makes more sense to draw a rectangle using 'rectangle' than it does to make a fat line.