# sorting integer representations of color - android

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

Below is a drawing tool class that i am using as like a brush tip.  For a drawing application.

In my main activity i have an arrayList of this object type and I would like to sort them by color.

As you can see i have a compareTo method that just returns int1-int2 (where ints are the color values of each tool..  but this does not sort them in the way i expected.

I am trying to sort them by color like a rainbow.

Now i know this would probably be easier if they were of type Color rather than Int, but data source will be returning Int values like 0xff000000 for black.

```
public class KNDrawingTool implements Comparable<KNDrawingTool>{

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public int size;
    public int color;
    public int cost;
    public int capacity;
    public int amountLeft;
    public String type;
    public Paint mPaint;


    public KNDrawingTool(String toolType, Boolean flatTip, int paintId, String paintName, int paintSize,int paintColor, int paintCost, int canCapacity, int remainingAmount){
        type = toolType;
        id = paintId;
        name = paintName;
        size = paintSize;
        color =paintColor;
        cost = paintCost;
        capacity = canCapacity;
        amountLeft = remainingAmount;

        mPaint = new Paint();

        if(type == "paint"){
           mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
        }
        /*if(flatTip){
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);  
        }else{
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        }*/
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setColor(color);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(size);



    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Comparable#compareTo(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(KNDrawingTool other) {
        Log.v("TOOL", "SOrting");
        return (color-other.color);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call `compareTo` method? And are you using `compareTo` method to sort a list? Can you give what kind of output are you getting?

Comment: in my main activity i have an ArrayList<KNDrawingTool> allTools;

and i just call Collections.sort(allTools);

Comment: it sorts them but i am wanting something like DarkRed, medium Red, red, DarkPurple, medium Purple, purple, Dark Blue.. etc.. but what i am getting is more like Dark Red, Dark Purple, Dark Blue, Medium Red, Medium Purple.. etc..

Comment: So basically you are trying to sort by Hex values?

Comment: If I understood correct, you need to sort them by `Hue` values. Convert your `hex` code to `hue` and then try to sort. This articles might help : [Sort (hex) colors to match rainbow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915113/sort-hex-colors-to-match-rainbow) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to convert your RGB color value to HSL/HSV and then sort by each of the components H=Hue, S=Saturation, (L=Lightness | V=Value). I will update this post with code soon.

CODE UPDATE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int[] COLORS = {
        Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED,
        Color.BLUE, Color.DKGRAY, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.LTGRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.GRAY,
        Color.CYAN, Color.WHITE, 0xFFCC0000,
        0xFF00CC00, 0xFF0000CC, 0xFFCCCC00,
        0xFF00CCCC, 0xFFCC00CC,
    };

    private static final int[] FOREGROUNDS = {
        android.R.attr.textColorPrimary,
        android.R.attr.textColorPrimaryInverse,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);

        ArrayList<KNDrawingTool> tools = new ArrayList<KNDrawingTool>();
        for(int i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++){
            tools.add(new KNDrawingTool(COLORS[i], "Color Entry #" + i));
        }
        Collections.sort(tools);

        final int foregrounds[] = new int[FOREGROUNDS.length];
        TypedArray taForegrounds = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(FOREGROUNDS);
        for(int i = 0; i < FOREGROUNDS.length; i++){
            foregrounds[i] = taForegrounds.getColor(i, Color.WHITE);
        }
        taForegrounds.recycle();

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<KNDrawingTool>(this, 0, tools)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                TextView text;
                if(convertView == null){
                    text = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
                }
                else{
                    text = (TextView)convertView;
                }
                KNDrawingTool item = getItem(position);
                text.setText(item.name);
                text.setBackgroundColor(item.color);
                if(item.hsv[2] > 0.5){
                    text.setTextColor(foregrounds[0]);
                }else{
                    text.setTextColor(foregrounds[1]);
                }
                return text;
            }
        });
        setContentView(listView);
    }


    private class KNDrawingTool implements Comparable<KNDrawingTool>
    {
        private int color;
        private String name;
        private float[] hsv = new float[3];

        public KNDrawingTool(int color, String name)
        {
            this.color = color;
            this.name  = name;
            Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(KNDrawingTool another)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                if(hsv[i] != another.hsv[i]){
                    return (hsv[i] < another.hsv[i]) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```