# C# - How do I order a list of colors in the order of a rainbow?

Tags: c#, colors, gradient

From a list of images, I calculated the average color using a method [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1068399/7918485). I now have a list of `System.Drawing.Color`, but I'm not sure how to sort them in a way that it looks like a rainbow.

Here is something simple I have tried (slightly changed for example purposes):

```
var colorList = new List<Color>
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Purple,
    Color.Black,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Green,
    Color.LightGreen,
    Color.LightSkyBlue,
    Color.Yellow
};

var orderedColorList =
    colorList.OrderBy(o => (o.R * 3 + o.G * 2 + o.B * 1));
```

This does not seem to create a rainbow but more of an effect from black to white.

How would I be able to sort them in a way that results in a rainbow?

Comment: I'll try to sort the colors by Red, then by Green and finally by Blue?

Comment: close duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915113/sort-hex-colors-to-match-rainbow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208980/sorting-a-list-of-rgb-triplets-into-a-spectrum - hint convert it to hsv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you order by the `Hue` first, and then `RGB`, you should get a rainbow ordering:

```
var orderedColorList = colorList
    .OrderBy(color => color.GetHue())
    .ThenBy(o => o.R * 3 + o.G * 2 + o.B * 1);
```

Using a mixed-up collection of rainbow colors, this appears to do the trick:

```
var colorList = new List<Color>
{
    Color.LightSkyBlue,
    Color.Red,
    Color.Yellow,
    Color.Purple,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Green
};

var orderedColorList = colorList
    .OrderBy(color => color.GetHue())
    .ThenBy(o => o.R * 3 + o.G * 2 + o.B * 1);

foreach (var color in orderedColorList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
}
```

**Output**

[image]