# Get a "rainbow gradient" from numeric values - PHP

Tags: php, colors

I want to have a gradient with rainbow colors.

I have numeric values, the maximum value is the color Red, and minimum value is the color Blue.
I try to find an algorithm to have proportional colors, i.e the half will be Green, between half and max will be Yellow or Orange....

I begin with this : [Get color value from numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777472/get-color-value-from-numeric-values)
But my function is not correct, if someone can help me... I try with HSV, RGB ... But I am more WebDesigner than Developper..
Thanks !

EDIT -----------------

This help ! Thanks a lot, I was sure that Value must be variable, but only with the Hue I get the right thing...

```
$h = ($value * 360) / $max;

$color = HSV_TO_RGB($h / 360, 1, 1);
```

First time, I forgot to divide by 360 to have a value between 0-1... I am an idiot. The HSV_TO_RGB function can be easily found on Web (hsv to rgb php in Google).
I get the right colors now, using a boucle.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show your code. We're not going to write the function for you - we're here to help, not do you job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicaly what you will need is a HSV to RGB function with fixed Value and Saturation (let's say 100 for saturation and value) and only change the Hue between 0 (your min value) and 360 (your max value).
You can find many hsv2rgb php implementation over the network and i think that should do the trick.

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](http://krazydad.com/tutorials/makecolors.php) to be extremely useful for creating a color palette and understanding how rainbows are generally generated.  I reccommend to read it thoroughly, to understand how to create both repeating and non-repeating color cycles of arbitrary length.

The javascript was easily translated to OpenCV Python as follows.  The `makeColorGradient` generates the list of RGB colors of specified `count`.  The rest of the code just tests it and displays the gradient nicely. Again refer to the tutorial for cool gradient types and values for the parameters. =)

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

def makeColorGradient(freq1, freq2, freq3,
                      phase1, phase2, phase3,
                      center=128, width=127, count=50):

    colors = []
    for i in range(count):
        red = int(math.sin(freq1*i + phase1) * width + center);
        grn = int(math.sin(freq2*i + phase2) * width + center);
        blu = int(math.sin(freq3*i + phase3) * width + center);
        #document.write( '<font color="' + RGB2Color(red,grn,blu) + '">&#9608;</font>');
        colors.append((red,grn,blu))
    return colors

def main():
    freq = 2.4 #non repeating color set
    #freq = 0.3 #nice happy rainbow =)
    phases = [0,2,4]
    count = 67 #number of colors to generate
    colors = makeColorGradient(freq,freq,freq,
                               phases[0],phases[1],phases[2],
                               count=count)
    winname = 'Color Gradient count='+str(count)
    cv2.namedWindow(winname)

    w = 800
    h = 100
    canvas = np.zeros((h,w,3),np.uint8)
    linspace = np.linspace(0,w,count,endpoint=True)
    linspace = map(int, linspace)
    for i in range(count-1):
        r1 = (linspace[i], 0)
        r2 = (linspace[i+1], h)
        color = colors[i]
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, r1, r2, color, thickness=cv2.cv.CV_FILLED)
    cv2.imshow(winname, canvas)

    #keep window open till escape key pressed
    while(1):
        if(cv2.waitKey(15) == 27):
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print 'done'
```