# How do I iterate through the visible spectrum of colours in RGB?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using freeglut to draw some shapes on screen, and wish to adjust their colours based on the values associated with each of the objects. The values range from `0.0` to `1.0`, and I want these to represent bright red to violet, with numbers linearly scaling through the visible spectrum.

Problem is, I need to represent these in RGB color codes (0.0 to 1.0 for each). Is there some simple way of achieving this?

Comment: RGB is not a good colour space to do this in.  I would look at working in [HSL or HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), which have a "hue" axis, and then converting back to RGB when necessary.

Comment: You could do that easily using HSL colors, iterating over the color chanel, and translating it to RGB

Comment: The main problem you'll encounter is, that RGB doesn't cover a large portion of the visible color space. If you really want to represent the whole visible spectrum you'll have to work in a wide gamut color space, or better yet in a contact color space. But be warned that *no* display device in widely available is able to represent all visible colors; technically it could be done with existing technology using video projectors that use more than 3 colors in their color filter wheel.

Comment: here is mine better wavelength -> RGB conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I didn't know about HSV. I found the following online:

```
void pSetHSV( float h, float s, float v ) {
    // H [0, 360] S and V [0.0, 1.0].
    int i = (int)floor(h/60.0f) % 6;
    float f = h/60.0f - floor(h/60.0f);
    float p = v * (float)(1 - s);
    float q = v * (float)(1 - s * f);
    float t = v * (float)(1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i) {
        case 0: glColor3f(v, t, p);
        break;
        case 1: glColor3f(q, v, p);
        break;
        case 2: glColor3f(p, v, t);
        break;
        case 3: glColor3f(p, q, v);
        break;
        case 4: glColor3f(t, p, v);
        break;
        case 5: glColor3f(v, p, q);
    }
}
```

Source: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/hsv-color-setting/770

Comment: Why wouldnt the regular RGB space work ? Something like http://www.astrouw.edu.pl/~jskowron/colors-x11/rgb.html ?