# Variable not taking any value (c)

Tags: c

It may be a dumb thing that I didn't saw but I've got the a really strange behavior on my program.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void spectral_color(double r,double g,double b,double l); //https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double r,g,b;
    spectral_color(r,g,b,600);
    //printf("%lf,%lf,%lf",r,g,b);
}

void spectral_color(double r,double g,double b,double l) // RGB <0,1> <- lambda l <400,700> [nm]
    {
    double t;  r=0.0; g=0.0; b=0.0;
    if ((l>=595.0)&&(l<650.0)) { 
        t=(l-595.0)/(650.0-595.0); 
        r=(double)0.98+(0.06*t)-(0.40*t*t); 
    }
    printf("%lf,%lf,%lf",r,g,b);
}
```

It prints `0.000000,0.000000,0.000000` and I tried this in the gdb

```
15          t=(l-595.0)/(650.0-595.0); 
(gdb) p l
$8 = 600
(gdb) p r
$9 = 1.7802772279180279e-307
(gdb) p t
$10 = 2.4846118548532686e+264
(gdb) n
16          r=(double)0.98+(0.06*t)-(0.40*t*t); 
(gdb) p t
$11 = 0.090909090909090912
(gdb) p r
$12 = 1.7802772279180279e-307
(gdb) n
18      printf("%lf,%lf,%lf",r,g,b);
(gdb) p t
$13 = 0.090909090909090912
(gdb) p r
$14 = 1.7802772279180279e-307
```

Here, `r` do not take the value it should and I have no idea why it would do that.
Do someone have an explanation ?

Thanks in advance

edit:

I passed the value of `r` to another variable and changed the `%lf` to `%f`,
the result is that `r` is never equal to the new variable but the correct value ends up in this new variable

```
double d = r; //this is line 18
printf("%f,%f,%f",d,g,b);
```

gdb result:

```
20  }
(gdb) p d
$1 = 0.98214876033057852
(gdb) p r
$2 = 1.7802772279180279e-307
(gdb)
```

Comment: You have Undefined Behaviour. You are using uninitialised variables.

Comment: try `printf("%f,%f,%f",r,g,b);`

Comment: Wow, okay, it works with `%f` can you explain me ?

Comment: I think your compiler can not handle `lf` properly (or mismatch library).

Comment: It shows the correct value with the print but if I look with gdb, `r` is never equal to the value printed

Comment: To be clear, you are talking about the printf inside the `spectral_color` function? The one you have commented out in `main` obviously won't work , even if you uncomment it

Comment: `0.000000` is the correct output for `%f` (or `%lf`) and the value `1.7802772279180279e-307`

Comment: With `double r,g,b;
    spectral_color(r,g,b,600);`, what value do you think  `r` has when `spectral_color(r,...)` is called?

Comment: to understand this compiler behavier, you probably need to read assembly file that compiler generated.`gcc -S file.c`

Comment: what's the point of passing r, g and b when you set them as 0 anyway?

Answer (score -1):

Once I have been bothered by this problem until I read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

This is the explanation of the `l` length modifier

`(ell) A following integer conversion corresponds to a long int or unsigned long int argument, or a following n conversion corresponds to a pointer to a long int argument, or a following c conversion corresponds to a wint_t argument, or a following s conversion corresponds to a pointer to wchar_t argument.`

Maybe a picture could be more illustrating
[image]

There would be a type promotion or conversion performed if you use the length modifier of `l` for a `double`. That's probably the reason of your confusion.

Comment: *"By the way, I always use `L` for a `float` or `double` conversion."* That makes no sense at all. As shown in your table, uppercase `L` is reserved for `long double`.

Comment: *"There would be a type promotion or conversion performed if you use the length modifier of `l` for a `double`"* Length modifiers don't affect type promotion. `double` is always passed as `double` to `printf` unless there is some non-standard compiler behaviour going on.

Comment: I don't see how you using `long double` is relevant to the problem. Question doesn't use `long double`.

Comment: @user694733 Maybe I was totally wrong. Could you please tell me why the `l` length modifier causes the `double` to `0`?