# Is it possible to plot a horizon gradient color filled under the curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient, image-gallery, multiple-variable-return

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081361/pyplot-vertical-gradient-fill-under-curve/22081678#22081678) is an example of vertical gradient color filled under a curve.

I would like a variation: the color filled under the curve represents a 'feature' of the variable. For example:
[image]

In the second subplot, the grey line is the feature importance of GPP (a variable), and the yellow line is the value of GPP. So, can I just plot one line representing the evolution of GPP, and fill the gap between this line and x-axis with a horizon gradient color? 'horizon gradient' means that, the deeper the filled color is, the larger the feature importance is. And the colorbar (of the filled color) involves the timing-evolution of feature importance.

By the way, I have 4 input variables and 3 output observation labels on multiple groups (4 different vegetation types, that means 4X and 3Y for each individual vegetation type). How can I plot their time evolution efficiently? (without needing to plot a HUGE amount of subplots.)

Comment: Check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959955/matplotlib-color-under-curve-based-on-spectral-color/44960748#44960748

Comment: You can use matplotlib's `fill_between()`: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321835/is-it-possible-to-get-color-gradients-under-curve-in-matplotlib) can be adapted to your use case?

Comment: wow, thanks you guys! I will check those approaches. (sorry I don't know how to reply you individually...)

Comment: @JohanC Thanks but unfortunately it's vertically gradient...And I prefer horizontally gradient color filled...

Comment: Well, that's why it needs adaption for your case: swap the x and the y direction. But it will take some work to get everything perfect.