# Realistic visible spectrum in Python

Tags: matplotlib, physics, spectrum

I want to include a color bar with a realistic visible spectrum with `cmap`, something close to:
[image]

However, there is no realistic visible spectrum from `cmap`, one that is closer seems to be `nipy_spectral`, good looking but not resembling something like above (especially on the width of some color, that there should be some wider some narrower color range observed from a realistic visible spectrum).

[image]

Comment: Its relatively straightforward to make a colormap yourself if you know the colors: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html

Comment: Try using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959955/matplotlib-color-under-curve-based-on-spectral-color)