# Python: matplotlib: zorder: Rock-paper-Scissors-like handling of zorder drawing priority

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, grid, z-order

In Matplotlib, in many drawing and configuration methods, you can set the `zorder` keyword to determine which elements are drawn on top of which ones. Now, my application would require a specific kind of handling or `zorder` as follows:

- Element A is drawn on top of element B
- Element B is drawn on top of element C
- Element C is drawn on top of element A

in a cyclic manner, like in rock-paper-scissors (`A` on top of `B` on top of `C` on top of `A` ------- `Rock` beats `Scissors` beats `Paper` beats `Rock`). I.e. there is no absolute zorder, but only pairwise.

- Element A is `ax.imshow`
- Element B is `ax.fill_between`
- Element C is `ax.grid`

In addition, element D is a plot drawn on top of everything else, but that is easy to implement when the rest is working.

Particularly, Element C i.e. the grid should be below everything except element B, the `fill_between`, which however should cover element A, the `imshow`

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure

fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
ax = fig.subplots()

x, y, X = ... # some data, details do not matter here

ax.plot(x, y, zorder=???)                                          # Element D
ax.imshow(X, ..., zorder=???)                                      # Element A
ax.fill_between(x, y, zorder=???)                                  # Element B
ax.set_axisbelow(True) # Set True or False, does it matter?
ax.grid(..., zorder=???)                                           # Element C
```

For details and context, this is related to [Matplotlib - color under curve based on spectral color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959955/matplotlib-color-under-curve-based-on-spectral-color) where a grid should be below the rainbow but above the white area.