# Convert a floating point number to RGB vector

Tags: opengl, qt5, colormap

I need to render a couple of cubes by opengl, and the color of every cube depends on the the magnetic field at the center of cube, but I don't know how to convert the float number into the `QVector3D` or `glm::vec3 (RGB)`.

And I can convert the range of the float array  between 0 and 1， I need to know how to convert the magnetic field array to RGB to define the color array.

Comment: you can try this [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) just change (scale) your floating point parameters to match visible light wavelengths ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you want to represent a floating point value in the range [0.0, 1.0], by a RGB color.
I recommend to transform the value to the [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV) color range.

[image]

For the full range the conversion is:

```cpp
float value = ...; // value in range [0.0, 1.0]

float H = value;
float R = fabs(H * 6.0f - 3.0f) - 1.0f;
float G = 2.0f - fabs(H * 6.0f - 2.0f);
float B = 2.0f - fabs(H * 6.0f - 4.0f);  

glm::vec3 color( 
    std::max(0.0, std::min(1.0, R))
    std::max(0.0, std::min(1.0, G))
    std::max(0.0, std::min(1.0, B)));
```

If you don't want the full range, for example, if you want to use the range from red to blue, then `value` has to be scaled:

```cpp
float H = value * 2.0f/3.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some form of lookup table (LUT). A RGB vector has 3 dimensions, a single float just one. There's literally an infinite number of ways how to map between those two.