# Mathplotlib set plot color based on an object id

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb

I have some python Objects with some data in them, and all of them have an id ( 1,2,3,4,5 ..... n). I have a python function where I send one of these objects and I want to plot the data from it, and the color to be different based on the id. I tried to do some things i've seen from other questions, like trying to convert the id integer into an RGB value, like this:

```
Blue =  integer & 255
Green = (integer >> 8) & 255
Red =   (integer >> 16) & 255

return (RED/255, Green/255, Blue/255)  # to get them into [0,1] interval
```

But the problem with that is that the color will be the same between close number like 1,2,3 (basicaly will have the same color almost). Any way to do this ?

EDIT:

So i was thinking of doing something like this:

```
def rgb_function(object_id):
    
    random.seed(object_id)
    value = random.uniform(0,1)
    #then calculate RGB value based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178857/convert-a-floating-point-number-to-rgb-vector
     H = value;
     R = abs(H * 6 - 3) - 1;
     G = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 2);
     B = 2 - abs(H * 6 - 4);  
     return max(0, min(1, R)), max(0, min(1, G)), max(0, min(1, B))
```

Comment: How large is n?

Comment: It depends how many objects are gonna be created based on some criteria, i'd say around 600 in average, but its kinda dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get away with just shuffling a colormap with a wide variety of colors so that it gets randomized.

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

colors = [plt.cm.hsv(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 600)]
# random.seed(77) # uncomment this if you want the same colors everytime
random.shuffle(colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(20), range(20), colors[:20]

# this gives different colors for ids that are similar
```

If you want truly random colors, you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520273/5345699) answer. But maybe that is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for answer krm, i did something different, generating a random float between [0, 1] and then calculating the RGB value ( see my EDIT), do you think something like that is correct?

Comment: Your changes LGTM. This is guaranteed to generate different colors for sure.

Comment: Yea, i guess another problem i would have is that sometimes the generated colors are to bright, for example there's a bright yellow color generated and when i plot the points with that color, they're kinda hard to see. Any way to lower the brightness?