# P5.js fluid Rainbow Effect

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, processing, p5.js

I am a just beginning with P5.js and i would like to create the effect shown in the image below.  I am not sure how to begin this.  I would appreciate any assistance on achieving this effect.

[image]

Comment: The [HSL Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSL_to_RGB) range is a good point to start with.

Comment: see [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) for the colors and use quadratic equation for the curve (you know variation of `y=x^2`).

Answer (score 5):

A complete answer to this question would be really broad. Possibly this is not a complete answer, but this are the first steps to one of many possible solutions.

Create a function, which maps a value in range [0, 1] a [HSL Color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSL_to_RGB):

```js
p.HUEtoRGB = function(H) {
    let R = Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 3.0) - 1.0;
    let G = 2.0 - Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 2.0);
    let B = 2.0 - Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 4.0);
    return [Math.max(0, Math.min(255, R*255)),
            Math.max(0, Math.min(255, G*255)),
            Math.max(0, Math.min(255, B*255))];
}
```

And create a function which generates a smooth edge:

```py
p.SmoothStep = function(edge0, edge1, x) {
    t = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, (x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0)));
    return t * t * (3.0 - 2.0 * t);
}
```

Use the function, to create an image with the rainbow colors from the left to the right ([`createImage()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createImage)) and an decreasing alpha channel to its borders:

```js
img = p.createImage(100, 10);
img.loadPixels();
for (let i = 0; i < img.width; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < img.height; j++) {
        let pi = 4*(j*img.width + i);
        
        // color dependent on u (column)
        let col = p.HUEtoRGB(1.0-i/img.width);

        // alpha dependent on the distance to the border
        let fx = p.SmoothStep(0, img.width/5, Math.min(i, img.width-i))
        let fy = p.SmoothStep(0, img.height/20, Math.min(j, img.height-j))
        let alpha = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, fx*fy*200))

        img.pixels[pi]     = col[0];
        img.pixels[pi + 1] = col[1];
        img.pixels[pi + 2] = col[2];
        img.pixels[pi + 3] = alpha;
    }
}
img.updatePixels();
```

Use a `WEBGL` canvas ([`createCanvas()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas)):

```py
p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight, p.WEBGL);
```

Create a curved band shape ([`beginShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape)):

```py
p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLE_STRIP)
p.texture(img)
let no = 20;
for (let i = 0; i <= no; ++ i ) {
    let ps = p.createVector(p.height/3-50, 0);
    let pc = p.createVector(p.height/3-50-10000, 0);
    let dir = p.createVector(-0.5, -1).normalize();
    let pd = p5.Vector.add(ps, p5.Vector.mult(dir, 10000*i/no));
    let p2 = p5.Vector.add(pc, p5.Vector.sub(pd, pc).normalize().mult(10000));
    p.vertex(-p.width/2,  p2.x, p2.y, 0, i/no);
    p.vertex( p.width/2,  p2.x, p2.y, 100, i/no);
}
p.endShape();
```

Use a perspective projection to look at the shape ([`perspective()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/perspective)):

```py
p.perspective(p.PI / 3.0, p.width / p.height, 0.1, 15000);
```

See the example:

```js
var sketch = function( p ) {
let img;

p.HUEtoRGB = function(H) {
    let R = Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 3.0) - 1.0;
    let G = 2.0 - Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 2.0);
    let B = 2.0 - Math.abs(H * 6.0 - 4.0);
    return [Math.max(0, Math.min(255, R*255)),
            Math.max(0, Math.min(255, G*255)),
            Math.max(0, Math.min(255, B*255))];
}

p.SmoothStep = function(edge0, edge1, x) {
    t = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, (x - edge0) / (edge1 - edge0)));
    return t * t * (3.0 - 2.0 * t);
}

p.setup = function() {
    let sketchCanvas = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight, p.WEBGL);
    sketchCanvas.parent('p5js_canvas');
    p.updateCamera();

    img = p.createImage(100, 100);
    img.loadPixels();
    for (let i = 0; i < img.width; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < img.height; j++) {
            let pi = 4*(j*img.width + i);
            
            // color dependent on u (column)
            let col = p.HUEtoRGB(1.0-i/img.width);

            // alpha dependent on the distance to the border
            let fx = p.SmoothStep(0, img.width/5, Math.min(i, img.width-i))
            let fy = p.SmoothStep(0, img.height/20, Math.min(j, img.height-j))
            let alpha = Math.max(0, Math.min(255, fx*fy*200))

            img.pixels[pi]     = col[0];
            img.pixels[pi + 1] = col[1];
            img.pixels[pi + 2] = col[2];
            img.pixels[pi + 3] = alpha;
        }
    }
    img.updatePixels();
}

p.windowResized = function() {
    p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    p.updateCamera();
}

p.updateCamera = function() {
    p.perspective(p.PI / 3.0, p.width / p.height, 0.1, 15000);
}

p.draw = function() {
  
    p.background(255, 255, 255, 0);

    p.push();
    p.translate(0, 0, -5); 
    p.texture(img)
    p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLE_STRIP)
    let no = 20;
    for (let i = 0; i <= no; ++ i ) {
        let ps = p.createVector(p.height/2.2-50, 0);
        let pc = p.createVector(p.height/2.2-50-10000, 0);
        let dir = p.createVector(-0.5, -1).normalize();
        let pd = p5.Vector.add(ps, p5.Vector.mult(dir, 10000*i/no));
        let p2 = p5.Vector.add(pc, p5.Vector.sub(pd, pc).normalize().mult(10000));
        p.vertex(-p.width/2,  p2.x, p2.y, 0, 100*i/no);
        p.vertex( p.width/2,  p2.x, p2.y, 100, 100*i/no);
    }
    p.endShape();
    p.pop();
}

};

var rainbow_3d = new p5(sketch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<div id="p5js_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Really nice demo (+1). FWIW p5's [`colorMode(HSB)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/colorMode) could simplify the `HUEtoRGB` part