# How to get a consistent hash/spectra of n points given a 32-byte md5 string

Tags: string, algorithm, hash, curve

I would like to take an md5 hash of some content, and then generate a "curve" or a "spectrum" so to speak, of n points. That is, to plot let's say 5, 10, or 20 points on a line from 0 to 1, distributed in a way so that it's unique to the md5 hash (collisions don't much matter). Basically it would look like a atomic light emission spectrum.

[image]

[image]

These points (or lines in the spectra) are somehow generated based on the md5 hash provided, and the `n` provided saying how many lines you want.

So it would be like:

```
function generateSpecrum(md5, n) { return [ ... ] }
```

By default it could just return the values from between 0 and 1, but maybe you give it a start and end value from which to generate the range.

Wondering how this could be done, in pseudocode or in JS.

There will be however many possibilities of a standard md5 hash. I would just do this:

```
var crypto = require('crypto')
var data = 'foo'
crypto.createHash('md5').update(data).digest('hex')
// acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8
```

So a 32-byte string. In my case it doesn't need to produce globally unique values, there can be some collisions, but if there was a way for it to produce a variety of spectra from different md5 inputs, that would be cool.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do here. md5 hash is 128 bits or 16 bytes. It would be nice to divide it into groups of 8 bit triples to create RGB color lines, but 16 is not divisible by 3. So just reuse two of the 8 bit fields for the last color triple. This will give you 6 lines.

Comment: You can of course create more lines with less color resolution by choosing smaller bit fields. For example, by using 4 bits field you could have 11 lines, and with 3 bits fields you could have 15 lines.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Or you could do greyscale with 8 bits per line (0 being black, and 255 being white). Or map the 256 values to a [halftone palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone).

Comment: Come to think of it, you could use 5-bit fields. That would give you 25 different fields and 32 different colors that you can map to a 32-color half tone palette. You'd have three bits left over. I suppose you could make three of the fields 6 bits each. Or have a 26th field that can only display 8 different colors.

Comment: Why not use the Hash as a Seed for random and generate whatever using pseudo random generator? Like get number fo wavelengths and then the wavelenghts .... compute the RGB of wavelengths from [RGB values of visible spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) or from poor HSV approximation instead. ... so all boils down to 1+n Random calls

Comment: If you have a 32 byte print, you have 128 discrete bits to work with. That's _more_ than plenty (but for increased spectrum fidelity, use a sha print instead of md5, since that gives you 160 bits at minumum, with sha-256 being fast to compute these days, and giving oodles of bits). Then just treat each bit as "emits" vs "doesn't emit", and done. See answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ignore the part where the string data is an `md5` print and instead focus on how to do this for arbitrary length hexadecimal strings, so we can use any digest we like (from CRC32 to SHA-512):

1. start with a hue gradient background (we can do this in CSS),
2. turn the string into a bit print (built into JS), and
3. black out any region that corresponds to a zero bit.

As a runnable snippet:

```js
function hexstr2bin(stringinput) {
  // let's not be constrained by JS integer precision,
  // which is only good for 53 bits. Technically we don't
  // care what the "numbers" are here, we just want the
  // ones and zeros that the numbers turn into.
  return stringinput.split('').map(c => (
    parseInt(c, 16).toString(2).padStart(4,'0')
  )).join('');
}

function renderSpectrum(stringinput) {
  let cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
  let bits = Array.from(hexstr2bin(stringinput));

  cvs.width = bits.length;
  cvs.height = 1;
  ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
 
  bits.forEach( (bit,i) => {
    if (bit === "0") {
      ctx.moveTo(i,0);
      ctx.lineTo(i,1);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  });

  document.body.appendChild(cvs);
};

renderSpectrum("acbd18db4fccc4a4d8");
renderSpectrum("c5887c91d0002f2a869a4b0772827701");
renderSpectrum("06956ff032d78e090d0d292aa9d8e7143ab08cf1ed444944529f79a4f937306a");
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    violet, blue, cyan, green, yellow, orange, red
  );
}
```

And stretching the canvas to 100% width means you get blurring for free. Bonus!