# How to generate CSS color Gradients from C# controller in the following format

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, colors

###### Question:

> From my C# controller, how can I create/`calculate`/inject a set of `evenly distributed HTML compliant CSS colors` (Gradient), based on the variable number (Num. of Students Travelling)?   *I am also open to other ideas or a lib.*

*Background/Context*: the designer is expecting **the given output below**, to *apply those colors on a list of background divs*.

This `CSS will be the background-div` for the `Varying colors/distance travelled by the Student families nearest to farthest`. My apologies if it sounds basic, being new to browser colors formats ranges, and finding it confusing on how the `css math min/max in colors work between HSL and HEX` *for e.g. if they are interchangeable with windows color system, or Why are Hex Colors 3 digits sometimes and 6 others.*

##### Sample expected output

```
 // For e.g. the list of students is dynamic could be 5, 10 or 20.. so I need to generate a list of gradient CSS colors, that I can inject into the view.

.TravelDistance.Student1        { background: #F00; background: hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); }  // how to generate these backgrounds.. hsl(   0, 100%, 50%); 
.TravelDistance.Student2        { background: #F80; background: hsl(  36, 100%, 50%); }
.TravelDistance.Student3        { background: #FF0; background: hsl(  72, 100%, 50%); }
.TravelDistance.Student4        { background: #0F0; background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%); }
.TravelDistance.Student5        { background: #0F8; background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%); }
.TravelDistance.Student..N      { background: #0FF; background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%); }
```

---

So far, I found some help.. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246328/6085193)

```
public static IEnumerable<Color> GetCssColorGradients(start = CssColor.Min, end = CssColor.Max, int steps) // steps  = number of students
{
    if (steps < 3) return null;

    int stepA = ((end.A - start.A) / (steps - 1));
    int stepR = ((end.R - start.R) / (steps - 1));
    int stepG = ((end.G - start.G) / (steps - 1));
    int stepB = ((end.B - start.B) / (steps - 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        yield return Color.FromArgb(start.A + (stepA * i),
                                    start.R + (stepR * i),
                                    start.G + (stepG * i),
                                    start.B + (stepB * i));
    }
}

// found this class, how do I spread these with a stepper? Is there an object that handles hue, and css colors as one in .Net without reinventing the wheel.
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
float hue = color.GetHue();
float saturation = color.GetSaturation();
float lightness = color.GetBrightness();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl you can use the hsl function in your css style. Maybe as an element style on each div? `style="background: hsl(@(x *360/ count), 100%, 50%);"`

Comment: thanks @JeremyLakeman do I need both the  `style="background: hsl(@(x *360/ count), 100%, 50%);"` values with `background: #F00;` ? just trying to understand/wondering if both are needed in the above section in my question? or do the two backgrounds *do different things?* I also need to get to a more dynamic `cssHelper class`